# DateTime Null and mySql

Tags: php, datetime

I constantly run into this and there has to be a better way to do it. So I have an Order Class and an Order_db class. in the order class there is a property $orderDate that is a DateTime object.

The problem is that sometimes the $orderDate is null. So it seems I have to options:

1. When I do a select query I test to see if there was date before calling my setter. When I do an Insert query I check that $orderDate isn't null before trying to perform a ->format (as that would throw an error)
2. I test in the setter if anything was passed before creating a new DateTime object but I'm still stuck with testing if it exists before using it with ->format.

It's not that big of a deal but I deal with a lot of date fields and it gets pretty repetitive. Is there a better way to handle this? In my ideal world if I passed nothing to DateTime when creating a instance it would be null, and if I called ->format on a null DateTime it would return nothing instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DB`.`Exampletable` (
 `field_1` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `field_2` CHAR(20) NOT NULL default 'default_text',
 `field_3` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `field_4` BIGINT(20),
 `field_5` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Do you tried to add the Default NULL to the date's?

Comment: I know how to do it. In fact you don't need to check empty just $orderDate ? doSomething : something else . But if you have tables with 4 date fields and you have 30 tables not to mention all the times it's used on a web page it gets really repetitive.

Comment: What about that? i cant tell whay tou know, and what you dont know... But you can tell us what have you tried before... @Casey

Comment: I did. In both options I talked about testing to make sure it wasn't null.

Comment: Have you tried a field with a int field, with the fields with null dates maybein binary, 4 date fields=4 bits  1001 (first and last are null) so you check only 1 field